# why does my web browser's PrintPreviewDialog display become small when loaded in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I don't know why the size is small, is there something wrong or is there a way with the code so that the display becomes normal.

Thanks

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
           Using dt = LoadData("A")
            myWebBrowser.DocumentText = DataTableToHtml(dt)
        End Using
    End Sub
    Private Sub myWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles myWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted
        myWebBrowser.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
        'myWebBrowser.Print()
    End Sub
```

code in designer

```
    Friend WithEvents myWebBrowser As New WebBrowser
```

[image: screenshot webbrowser]

update code

```
   Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myWebBrowser.Parent = Me
End Sub
```

result after update code

[image: screenshot webbrowser with update code parent]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731657/14171304

Comment: @dr.null , 
received the link suggestion worked perfectly and I put code `myWebBrowser.Parent = Me` in form load . 
Is it true?

Comment: If it does work, then it is true.

Comment: @dr.null , yes, it is working. Thanks

Comment: @dr.null , Can you give me a link that can set the printer, paper, orientation with code for the web browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836345/how-to-set-paper-size-and-margins-printing-from-a-web-browser-control

Comment: @dr.null , 
thank you, I will try

Comment: Can't use the returned `DataTable` from your [pervious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77381209/14171304) question with the ReportViewer? Think about it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34512521/14171304 for example.

Comment: @dr.null , 
If before I used it from the class model list to the report viewer but I couldn't use it because of the property name `-` , `XXL/2L` . if I use a datatable then I still create each column from the datatable in the dataset but rdlc definitely doesn't accept the column name and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511856/pass-datatable-to-reportviewer/34512521#34512521)  this uses `Me.DataGridView1.DataSource` 
I don't want to display or use datagridview so I print directly from the datatable so I took the solution via HTML

Comment: @dr.null , `Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load myWebBrowser.Parent = Me  End Sub`
After updating the code the results are like what I posted, is there a solution?

Comment: Dock/Anchor your controls correctly or lay them out in layout panels. If the Form hosts the `WebControl`, then you don't need this `myWebBrowser.Parent = Me`. Select the `WebControl` and anchor it to left, top, right, bottom edges. The buttons to left, bottom.

Comment: @dr.null , means I have to add control from toolbox to  `WebBrowser`

Comment: @dr.null , without use from toolbox controll hence the solution after code `Private Sub myWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles myWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted myWebBrowser.Parent = Me myWebBrowser.visible=false myWebBrowser.ShowPrintPreviewDialog() End Sub` I used the final solution